# Highchart DateTime Axis: How to display non existent data as 0 or gap

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart in datetime mode, I give it a data with 7 categories/rows the lib is generating empty categories data (I have no data for February 2019, April 2019 ...) which is great so the interval on the categories axis stays as one month.
What should I do if I want to display missing data as 0 (empty data) ?

I can't just add null entries for February and April as my data comes from a dynamic array and I would like to avoid to loop on that array to find missing data.
I've setup a fiddle to help sorting this

https://jsfiddle.net/3qob5j49/

here's my xAxis setup

```
"xAxis": {
"type": "datetime",
"title": {
    "text": "",
    "align": "middle",
    "style": {
        "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
        "fontSize": "14px",
        "textShadow": "",
        "fontWeight": 400,
        "fontStyle": "italic",
        "textDecoration": "",
        "color": "rgba(62,78,91,0.5)"
    }
},
"categories": null,
"lineColor": "rgba(191,191,191,1)",
"lineWidth": 1,
"gridLineWidth": 0,
"gridLineColor": "rgba(242,242,242,1)",
"gridZIndex": 2,
"minorGridLineWidth": 0,
"minorGridLineColor": "#CCCCCC",
"tickColor": "transparent",
"tickLength": 5,
"crosshair": false,
"tickWidth": 0,
"labels": {
    "enabled": true,
    "rotation": 90,
    "step": null,
    "style": {
        "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
        "fontSize": "14px",
        "textShadow": "",
        "fontWeight": 400,
        "fontStyle": "",
        "textDecoration": "",
        "color": "rgba(127,127,127,1)"
    }
}
```

You can check the following [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmf7S.png) that describe what I'm trying to do.

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Damien Courouble, I am afraid that the only solution is to loop through the data array and add the missing values.

Comment: @ppotaczek How would you do that ? Like I said my data is dynamic so how do I know which one and where should I insert nulls ?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your data array to find too large time intervals and insert additional points in the right places:

```
var dynamicData = [
        [1538344800000, 2],
        [1541026800000, 3],
        [1543618800000, 4],
        [1546297200000, 5],
        [1551394800000, 6],
        [1556661600000, 8],
        [1561932000000, 9]
    ],
    maxInterval = 2682000000,
    i = 0;

for (; i < dynamicData.length - 1; i++) {
    if (dynamicData[i + 1][0] - dynamicData[i][0] > maxInterval) {

        dynamicData.splice(
            i + 1,
            0, [dynamicData[i][0] + (dynamicData[i + 1][0] - dynamicData[i][0]) / 2, 0]
        )
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nwjL0omv/

Comment: that looks good but how do you come up with 2682000000 ? my tick interval might not be of one month everytime so it's not easy to find the "missing" points automatically.

Comment: Hi @Damien Courouble, That is a very important value. You have to calculate it somehow. You can provide me with more of your data and maybe we'll come up with something together.

Comment: Like I said my data are dynamics so don't know what to expect they could be daily data, monthly intervals like our example or anything else (maybe without missing points too). Is there a way to know which "interval" highchart will be using ? in that case that would be our maxInterval and your logic still applies.

Comment: @Damien Courouble - So, maybe we need to find the smallest interval between points?